# Which Canadian visa to apply for when visiting relatives in Canada who didn't issue an invitation?

Tags: visas, canada

My mother will be accompanying me for my travel to Canada. I have a PR visa, but she will have to take a visitor visa. What should be written as the purpose of her visa? Is "Tourism" the right purpose or should I write as "Others". Writing 'Others' as the purpose asks for the submission of a letter of invitation, but there is no one presently in Canada who can give the letter of invitation. I will be landing for the first time as an immigrant.

Comment: Well... why is she going to Canada with you? Yes to visit, but why? To be a tourist? To work? To study?

Comment: She is accompanying me while I settle there. I am going there as a landed immigrant. She is coming there to help me out in my initial 2-3 weeks as I have no one there. After that she will go back.

Comment: Tourism is totally fine. She's just visiting to look at the place and see relatives (you). She's not planning to work or study.

Answer (score 1):

Her purpose is 'Tourism', hence use that on the application. That's all there is to it.